# Subconsulta en Mysql

Tags: mysql

estoy tratando de obtener las horas por turno (turno_1, horas_extras) de cada sección (General, OP, Patio, Wladimir). Actualmente obtengo los resultados de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi consulta sql que utilizo es:

```
SELECT IFNULL(turno, 'Total') as turno, IFNULL(tipo_hora,'Total') AS seccion, SUM(hh) AS horas_totales FROM registros.v_pr_produccion
WHERE MONTH(fecha) = 3 AND YEAR(fecha) = 2021
GROUP BY turno, tipo_hora
WITH ROLLUP
```

Lo que me gustaría obtener sería algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero como se ve en la última imagen la columna horas_extras me esta mostrando la suma en todas las secciones, para esta consulta estoy intentando así;

```
SELECT IFNULL(tipo_hora,'Total') AS seccion, SUM(hh) AS turno_1, 
(SELECT SUM(hh) FROM registros.v_pr_produccion
WHERE MONTH(fecha) = 3 AND YEAR(fecha) = 2021 AND turno = 'hora extra') AS horas_extras
FROM registros.v_pr_produccion
WHERE MONTH(fecha) = 3 AND YEAR(fecha) = 2021 AND turno = 'Turno 1'
GROUP BY tipo_hora
WITH ROLLUP
```

Es posible obtener el resultado que deseo?

De antemano gracias.

Comment: Has intentado con el CASE WHEN?

Comment: Intenta reproducir tus tablas acá http://sqlfiddle.com/ para que sea mucho más fácil ayudarte.